Dynamic Features Modules And Its usage
I want to use Dynamic Feature modules in my application. Do I necessarily have to publish my app on the Play Store to use this feature? Is it not possible to use this feature without publishing the app on the Play Store?

Dynamic Feature Modules rely on Google Play functionality to deliver feature modules according the the configured delivery method.
If your app is available in the Play Store and elsewhere, you could potentially use DFMs for the Play Store version by uploading an App Bundle but would have to use a universal APK to distribute elsewhere.
If your app is not available in the Play Store, there is no benefit in using DFMs. Do not complicate your life and just use regular modules.
